# Xamarin Foms best behaviors and validation

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, behavior

I need to know how can I access my viewmodel the IsValid property of these behaviors.

I'd rather you tell me a more robust behavior, because they are made from scratch, I would like to make a more robust validation with some nuget package already advanced despite being new to Xamarin Forms.

This is my behavior, but I can not access the property "IsValid" my viewmodel:

```
  public class MesesTrabalhadosValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
        {
            private static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(MesesTrabalhadosValidatorBehavior), false);

            public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

            public bool IsValid
            {
                get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
                private set { base.SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
            }

            private void bindable_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                double result;
                double.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out result);
                IsValid = result > 0;

                ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            }

            protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
            {
                bindable.TextChanged += bindable_TextChanged;
            }

            protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
            {
                bindable.TextChanged -= bindable_TextChanged;
            }
        }
```

My view:

```
    <Entry Placeholder="Mêses trabalhados" Text="{Binding MesesTrabalhados}" Keyboard="Numeric">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
            <local:MesesTrabalhadosValidatorBehavior />
          </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>

        <Entry Placeholder="Último salário" Text="{Binding Salario}" Keyboard="Numeric">
          <Entry.Behaviors>
            <local:SalarioValidatorBehavior />
          </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>

    <ContentView Padding="0,20,0,0">
      <Button Text="Calcular" HorizontalOptions="Fill" IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid}" Command="{Binding CalcularFgtsCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </ContentView>
```

Comment: I am not sure at a 100%, but this feels more as a code review stackexchange question than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a parameter, my preference is a command function, so that you can call it when it reaches certain conditions. e.g.

```
<local:SalarioValidatorBehavior Command="{Binding MyCommandInViewModel}" />
```

Then the bindable property in the behavior.

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextChangedBehavior), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (Command != null)
            Command.Execute(null);
    }
```

or you can use your IsValid property in the Behaviour and then bind that back to a property in your ViewModel.

```
<local:SalarioValidatorBehavior IsValid="{Binding IsValid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: My command must be activated by clicking the button, it is with binding for this command.

If I am right that answer will automatically call the command, but it is not what I want. You know how to fix? You can change the answer once you arrive at work I test the change.

Comment: @LuizNegrini - try a two way binding on the IsValid property as shown above.

Comment: @AdamPedley Can you please take a look at this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679889/multiple-behaviors-in-entrybindable-property-change-is-not-reflected